# When I drag an image in NSTextAttachment it is an .rtf

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextattachment

I have an `NSTextView` that display an image like this.

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSImage *attachImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Settings"];
attachment.image = attachImage;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString  attributedStringWithAttachment: attachment];
[[self.textView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attributedString];
```

The image appears correctly, but I am not able to drag the  image out of the textfield onto my desktop. Every time I try I end up getting an .rtf file instead of an image. Anyway around this issue?

Comment: What does the `.rtf` file look like, is there data in it? You need specific code to properly handle drag operations with images.

Comment: No data inside it at all.